# Image of the object within .STL File

Tags: image, file, stl, 2d, extract

Please take a look on the website http://quotes.rapidprototype.com.au/upload/ and upload STL File and press "Start Upload" button. You shall see the image of the object within the stl file as (.png) image. I want the same functionality(The image of the of the object within the stl file, rest of the work i can do). I want to get the image in .png or .jpr or .gif format as a 2D image. I want that the user can see the image of the object within the stl file that he/she uploads. I am using PHP.

Please assist me how can I achieve this using PHP. I shall be very thank full to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ParaView www.paraview.org in the backend. This is free and reads stl as well as having the ability to save images. There is a python interface, so you can program it to do various things (starting by tracing your actions in the GUI). You can also give it options from the command line. ParaView has a web component, but it would probably be easier just to have PHP do a system call and look for the resulting image.

Test that it works on the command line before wrapping it in PHP